# SequelizeHostNotFoundError for Render deployed Database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-connection, render

I am trying to connect to a Postgres database hosted on [Render](https://render.com/docs/databases) using Sequelize ORM. I have the following database connection logic. I have added `ssl:true` to connect to externally manage database. I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <host-name>:5432
    at connection.connect.err (/<filepath>/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:175:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/<filepath>/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:213:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/<filepath>/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:57:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'SequelizeHostNotFoundError',
  parent:
   { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <host-name>:5432
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: '<host-name>',
     host: '<host-name>',
     port: 5432 },
  original:
   { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <host-name>:5432
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: '<host-name>',
     host: '<host-name>',
     port: 5432 } }
```

`db.js`:

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(proces.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING, {
    dialect: "postgres",
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: true,
    },
  });


async function test() {
try {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
}


test();
```

Note:

1. `DB_CONNECTION_STRING` in stored as environment variables.
2. Hostname is taken from Render page and it is correct.